# Looking for a free computer-ish, shaded, hollow font

Tags: font-recommendation

Our club zine is ages old; fancy headlines 40 years ago were made with a Sinclair Spectrum. I'd like to emulate this. Scanned example:

[image: 1. Bundesliga 1985]

I searched myself blue in the face on free font sites - either the font is too fancy for me (say, Fenotype Letters - a more "teletype"-ish look is what I want) or the shadow in the wrong direction (say TypoSlab Irregular Demo - boy, am I picky).

Any suggestion what font comes close? (Even better if HTML can render the font without fallback so I can use it on the zine website.)

(note added in edit: While the answer by Billy Kerr looks great, it also looks like work - I have literarily thousands of headlines. Writing a small Python code converting all (headline tag)"Headline" to (headline tag FONT=...) is trivial in comparison. I now check if I know enough CSS to do Yorik's suggestion. Here the conversion should also be automatizable.)

Comment: This is just white type with an outline and a drop shadow. This can easily be achieved using css, in svg, or even Word.

Comment: I recall a font like this… whilst trying to find it I suddenly discovered how few font devs know what the 80s actually looked like. There's everything from PT Barnum to that 60s/70s 'droopy' disco font, a bit like Dyslexia on drugs. Something you'd expect Woodstock to be advertised with. Man!

Comment: @Yorik: Please convert to answer to cash in your karma :-) I already just did a CSS with text-shadow which looks sufficiently good - maybe simply a link to here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4919076/outline-effect-to-text I simply wasn't aware that CSS can do that :-) I just now have to convert the teletype tags into font-face, link the css file externally and write the Python converter.

Comment: I think such fonts existed on C64 or Atari. Not as a TTF, probably.

Comment: Wrong way shadow: https://www.urbanfonts.com/fonts/Extrude.font

Answer (score 1):

You could replicate this almost exactly. Start with a pixel font such as ZX Spectrum which is available [on dafont here](https://www.dafont.com/zx-spectrum.font)

1. In some vector software, such as Illustrator or Inkscape, type the text and convert the text to paths
2. Add an offset to thicken up the text, set a thin black stroke and set the fill to white.
3. Then duplicate the text, set the fill to black and move it slightly up and to the right, then send to the back.

An example made in Inkscape

[image]click to see larger

Finally save as SVG, and use the SVG in your web page. Since everything is outlines, you won't have to worry about fallback fonts for display on a web page.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the result based on the hint Yorik gave me. I used the (somewhat nonstandard) text-shadow property of CSS. I merely have to redirect the h2 tag (in which all headlines are written anyway) for the ca. 50 issues that were written in Sinclair time, and insert a line

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../../pic/shadow.css">
```

inside the html head tag in those issues. The CSS file is simply

```
h2
{
    color: white;font-size:20pt;font-family: 'Courier New', monospace;
    text-shadow:
    1px 0 0 #000, 
    0 1px 0 #000, 
    -1px 0 0 #000, 
    0 -1px 0 #000,
    3px -3px 0 #000; 

}
```

and a sample result is

[image: Same headline, with CSS]

Not perfect (I could also set it in TT tags to make it even more typewriter-ish) but close enough (and who owns stone-old issues of the club zine to compare anyway :-)

EDIT: Using a ZX Spectrum font directly as suggested by Billy and Wolff, this is the result:

[image: ZX Spectrum]

Looks good! (Perhaps the shadow can be enlarged a bit.)

Comment: If you also used a pixel font like the one @BillyKerr links to, you could get even closer.

Comment: @Wolff: ...for the price that this font may be not "HTML safe". Would have to ask my "customers" if their computer displays it correctly. Worth an experiment.

Comment: The idea of "web safe fonts" is a bit dated as I understand it. It's very common to use non system fonts for web sites. And you can always add Courier New as a fallback. Like this: `font-family: 'ZX Spectrum', 'Courier New', monospace;`

Comment: @Wolff: Many THX! I knew CSS "fallback", but forgot the syntax. You spared me some research :-)

Comment: You need to place the font on your server as well and import it in your css.

Comment: That simply works? Computer (and languages) have evolved since Sinclair ZX :-)

Comment: Yeah, since the font is free you can. Read about the [@font-face CSS at-rule](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@font-face).

Comment: @Wolff: Neat. Too bad that "whole dir CSS" isn't possible https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32514524/default-css-file-for-directory unless this has changed too (or I learn a bit of PHP :-)

Comment: That's a specific coding issue with the way your site is built. You should ask questions about that on stack overflow.